# Convert a a character column to date with multiple formats

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate, stringr

Here's my starting example data from excel (next time, I'm going to teach my client about tidy data):

```
date_string  
3/13, 3/17, 3/20  
4/13  
5/12, 5/20
```

I get pretty close to what I want with this:

```
 library(tidyverse)  
 library(stringr)  
    data <- str_split_fixed(data$date_string, ",", 3)%>%  
    as_tibble() %>%  
    gather() %>%
    filter(value != "")
```

then I'm left with this:

```
key    value
v1    3/13  
v1    43203  
v1    5/12  
v2    3/17
v2    5/20
v3    3/20
```

This is good enough that I can do the rest of the formatting and arranging in excel, but the more I can do in R the better, especially as I'll have to do this all again next time I update the final product.  I feel like there is a `lubridate` function to help me with this but `mdy` and `date` keep returning errors.

The value I want is the table above but in m/d/y format.

**Update**

Based on the answer below I added the following.  This works, but there's probably a more elegant way to do it:

```
   data <- str_split_fixed(data$date_string, ",", 3)%>%  
    as_tibble() %>%  
    gather() %>%
    filter(value != "") %>%  
    mutate(value =  
     if_else(
      str_detect(value, "/") == T,
      paste0(value, "/2018"),
      as.character(as_date(as.numeric(value), origin = "1900-01-01")))) %>%        
    mutate(value =
     if_else(
      str_detect(value, "/") == T,
      mdy(value),
      ymd(value)))
```

I get these warnings, but the data is how I want it:

```
1. In as_date(as.numeric(value), origin = "1900-01-01") :  
 NAs introduced by coercion
2. 1 failed to parse.
3. 5 failed to parse.
```

Not sure how it "failed to parse" when the final "value" column is returned as a date variable . . .

Comment: You should share your expected output. Also, when you get errors they come with error messages to help you solve the problem. You should share the errors that you get.

Comment: I think you'll need to do a little conditional testing to call the right function with the right arguments on the right row. You'll also need to do some more data adjusting `"3/13"` isn't in `mdy` format because there's no year. Use `paste` to stick on whatever year you want, something like `ifelse(grepl("/" value), paste0(value, "/2001"), value)` to stick a `/2001`on any `value`s that already have a `/` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

First, add the year to your dates:

```
dates <- ("3/13", "4/17", "5/12", "3/17", "5/20", "3/20")
dates <- paste0(dates, "/18")
```

Second, convert them specifying the format (m/d/y in your case):

```
  as.Date(dates,  "%m/%d/%y")
  [1] "2018-03-13" "2018-04-17" "2018-05-12" "2018-03-17" "2018-05-20" "2018-03-20"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

data <- c(
"3/13, 3/17, 3/20",
"4/13",
"5/12, 5/20")

df <- tibble(date_string = data) %>% 
  mutate(date_string = str_split(date_string, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(date_string = ymd(str_c("2018-", date_string)))
df
```